# remove() - Called object 'remove' is not a function

Tags: c, function

**So I've tried from another post to make this code:**

```
while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;];%d; %49[^\n]",fileName,&seconds,timeValue) == 3)
{
    count++;
    if(count == linha)
    {
         fprintf(tempFile,"%s;%d;%s\r\n",orderNameFile,orderSecondsFile,orderTimeFile);
    }
    else
    {
         fprintf(tempFile,"%s;%d;%s\r\n",fileName,seconds,timeValue);
    }
}

fclose(tempFile);
fclose(orderFile);
remove("order.txt");
rename("temp.txt","order.txt");
```

**I also have included the stdio.h lib**

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

**Yet when I run this code, it gives an error on the remove function, saying:**

> error: called object 'remove' is not a function or function pointer

I've tried to create a char name[] = "order.txt"; and use it inside the **remove();** instead but didn't work as well, also already created an int variable like ***int x;*** **x =** **remove("order.txt");** and it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see my answer on your other question?

Comment: You probably have a variable called `remove` somewhere in your code, or are missing a ; somewhere. Post a minimal example of your entire code, so everyone can see the same as you see on your screen.

Comment: @Igor it's a standard C library function: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_remove.htm

Comment: @PaulRoub Impressive. Very nice. Had no idea.

Comment: Yeah, it was a function. Should learn more about those standard functions otherwise I'll do more of this type of errors :/ Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable named `remove` somewhere in your code, rename it.

Comment: Oh, you saved my life. I never really understood this type of error as I have a bit of difficulty to understand what these errors are as never got explained about it when it happens. Now I do know. Really thank you very much. :) It works now.

Comment: Yes but it said "Wait 4 more minutes" and as I was coding I forgot. Sorry.